# Definir uma função analítica em python

Tags: python, matriz

Preciso fazer algumas operações com matrizes (de dimensão muito grande), mas os elementos da mesma são funções analíticas. Existe uma forma de fazer isso em Python?

Ex:

Matriz = [[x**2+3x,x+y+1]...[...].....[...]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Será isto que estás à procura?

http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/sympy.html#matrices